# Saving php file - what encoding should I use to work with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, notepad++

I have one php file when I get data from MySQL where I set encoding to utf8. When Im tring to get data and display it in my php file I see there is sth wrong with some characters, e.g `Magia ĹwiÄt w JaseĹkach 2013-12-23`. 
I create all php files using utf8 encoding, but when I want to open this file from server Notepad++ showes me that there is ANSI as utf8 encoding and newline format is Macintosh.

Connecting to db

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('############');
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
  if($db->connect_error) {
      $msg = "Cant connect";
  } else {
    $msg = "Works!";
  }
?>



<?php
require '../bootstrap/bootstrap.php';
$query = $db->real_escape_string("Select id, data_dodania,tytul, zajawka From artykuly ORDER BY data_dodania DESC");
$result = $db->query($query);
$result=$result->fetch_all();
    foreach($result as $row ) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
          echo '<b>';
            echo $row[2];
            echo "<span class='text-info'> <small class='text-right'>$row[1] </small></span>";
          echo '</b>';
          echo '<br />';
          echo $row[3]; 
        echo '</td>';      

        echo '</tr>';

    } 
   echo '</table>';
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: Also, don't escape complete queries, just the values you want to use in them (although in this specific case it will not make a difference). Or better yet, use prepared statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I've added code to connect mysq

Comment: Regarding utf8 usage:  Are you setting both your notepad++ to edit your programs (not data) using utf8 as the encoding, AND setting the tables and fields (and possibly defaults on tables and fields and database) on MySQL so that your data is being saved in utf8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding you use on your Webpage and the encoding you have specified in the database setup. If the database connection use UTF-8 you probably should use UTF-8. There is no ANSI as UTF-8. Either you have UTF-8 or ANSI encoding.

In Notepad++ you can encode your file to UTF-8 if you go to `Encoding -> Convert to UTf-8`
Set this HTML-Tag to tell the browser, which encoding the browser should use for page display:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

In PHP to convert an ISO-8859-1 string, use `string utf8-encode(string $data)`
See here: [UTF8-Encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: I have the same encoding - in mysql i set it to utf8 and encoding for tables either. In my php file I (try to) use UTF8.

Comment: Go Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 in Notepadd++

Comment: I change encoding, newline format in n++ save it then open from server and encoding is again to ansi as utf8 and macintosh - new line format.

Comment: Have you set this Tag in your HTML-File?: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> helped :) I didnt know I have to add this to php files :). When I will just insert data to mysql should I use this tag too ?

Comment: If you use user input. Yes! If you only insert static data, that's already UTF-8: No. If you have an ANSI String, you have to use UTF8-Encode

Comment: Why do you disapprove my answer?